# Emgu CV unable to create capture from RTSP stream(H264),ip camera

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv

I have an ip camera in my local network with address `128.100.254.50` with http port `80` and rtsp port `554`. It is compro ip camera `ip540p`.

If I  type

```
rtsp://128.100.254.50:554/medias1
```

in browser it will redirecting to real player and will stream the current view of the ip webcam.

But when I try to put it in a vb.net

```
capture = new Capture("rtsp://128.100.254.50:554/medias1")
```

It return exception unable to create capture from

```
rtsp://128.100.254.50:554/medias1
```

I tried using

```
rtsp://username:password@128.100.254.50:554/medias1
```

yet the result end up to be same.

Wish to ask is there any step I had miss or the type return will affected the capture?

Had tried to research but many of similar situation didn't end of to have a fixed answer. Mostly is asking to ensure the address but I had successfully open it through real player...

Answer (score 0):

You can try different stream URL. Try URL from these :

http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Compro

If this dosen't work you can use software based media server like Flash Media Live Encoder, Unreal Media Server, Live555, FFServer FFMPEG etc to re-stream your RTSP feed to HLS(HTTP Live Streaming).